# Having trouble with a switch statement in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want my program to write out the number you typed in words. eg. 52 = fifty two.
What am i doing wrong here ???
It doesnt want to accept the words but i cant change the variables to strings either so im stuck !

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Switch
{

public static void main (String [] args )
{

int number = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in a number between 0 - 100 :") );

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;

    switch( num1 )
        { 
         case 1 : num1 = "One" ;break;
         case 2 : num1 = "Two";break;
         case 3 : num1 = "Three";break;
         case 4 : num1 = "Four";break;
         case 5 : num1 = "Five";break;
         case 6 : num1 = "Six";break;
         case 7 : num1 = "Seven";break;
         case 8 : num1 = "Eight";break;
         case 9 : num1 = "Nine";break;
            default:    System.out.println("Incorrect input");
                        break;
      }

      switch( num2 )
        {
         case 1 : num2 = "Teen";break;
         case 2 : num2 = "Twenty";break;
         case 3 : num2 = "Thirty";break;
         case 4 : num2 = "Fourty";break;
         case 5 : num2 = "Fifty";break;
         case 6 : num2 = "Sixty";break;
         case 7 : num2 = "Seventy";break;
         case 8 : num2 = "Eighty";break;
         case 9 : num2 = "Ninety";break;
            default:    System.out.println("Incorrect input");
                        break;
      }

      System.out.println(num1 + num2);

}

}
```

Comment: `int num1 = 0;` and `num1 = "One"`, you are using incompatible types here.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables num1 and num2 are integers and you are assigning string values to them. That won't work.
So you could have another string variable to store the values of the string.

But above all, your logic for converting the number to words  is wrong. Try debugging  and correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you assign `int num1 = 0; int num2 = 0;` before your switch, it's the same thing as writing:

```
switch(0) {}
```

Try to initialize correctly the `num1` and `num2`.

Also you try to put string to a int variable as @Matt Clark added.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the switch on num1 and num2 that are always 0 and not on the input. Also you are assigning string values to int types.

You will need to separate the input string to its digits using string[index] if you want to use switch to achieve what you want, however this does not seem like a very good way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign String to int variable in switch statement.
So first change data type of num1 and num2 to String.

```
String num1;
String num2;
```

Then in case statement it should case "1" not case 1

```
         case "1" : num1 = "One" ;break;
         case "2" : num1 = "Two";break;
         case "3" : num1 = "Three";break;
         case "4" : num1 = "Four";break;
         case "5" : num1 = "Five";break;
         case "6" : num1 = "Six";break;
         case "7" : num1 = "Seven";break;
         case "8" : num1 = "Eight";break;
         case "9" : num1 = "Nine";break;
```

If you are taking input as integer then convert integer to array of String

```
 int number = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in a number between 0 - 100 :") );

String num=Integer.toString(number);
char[] sNums = num.toCharArray();

String num2 =String.valueOf(sNums[0]) ;
String num1 = String.valueOf(sNums[1]);
```

In case if user inputs single digit then logic should be as follows:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Type in a number between 0 - 100 :"));

        String num = Integer.toString(number);
        char[] sNums = num.toCharArray();

        String num2 = String.valueOf(sNums[0]);
        String num1 = "";
        if (sNums.length > 1) {
            num1 = String.valueOf(sNums[1]);
        } else {
            num1 = num2;
            num2 = "";
        }
```